# Command-line start program in front after update

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file, command-line

I have used the following example to make an auto-update function for my c# winforms application. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29784/Updating-application-clients-with-a-Windows-Instal

With a few modifications to how it determines whether it is going to update or not. It all works very well except for one thing.

When the application has been updated and is started again it does not come to the front or even appear in the process line. If you press alt+tab you can see it and switch to it, and once you've done so it appears in the process line. Why is this? Can I make any alterations to the bat-file or perhaps the winforms application to change this?

Just to help a little, this is what the bat-file ends up looking like:

```
@echo off
ping localhost -n 2
C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /x {67BC5B51-1534-4C68-86C4-C74F4469C2BA} /qr 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /i "Z:\setup\MyAppSetup.msi" /qr
cd "C:\Program Files\Myapp"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Myapp\MyApp.exe"
```

Comment: Putting aside the reason why the application loosing focus, have you tried to set it programmatically on main form load event? It would be suffice workaround if it works.

Comment: @sburg The regular BringToFront etc. did not work, but ended up using  'public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);' which is part of user32.dll - so your comment got me working in the right direction - thanks a lot!